# How to plot a smooth curve in python for a list of values?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, curve, entropy

I have created a list of values of Shannon entropy for a pair of multiple sequence aligned sequences. While plotting the values I get a simple plot. I want to plot a smooth curve over the lines. Can anyone suggest to me what will be the right way to process it? BAsically I want to plot a smooth curve that touches the tip of every bar and goes to zero where the "y axis value" is zero.
link for image:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY3jH.png

```
#importing the relevant packages
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
from Bio import AlignIO
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

#function to calculate the Shannon Entropy of a MSA
# H = -sum[p(x).log2(px)]

def shannon_entropy(list_input):
    unique_aa = set(list_input)   
    M = len(list_input)
    entropy_list = []
    # Number of residues in column
    for aa in unique_aa:
        n_i = list_input.count(aa)                                           
        P_i = n_i/float(M)                                
        entropy_i = P_i*(math.log(P_i,2))
        entropy_list.append(entropy_i)
    sh_entropy = -(sum(entropy_list))
    #print(sh_entropy)
    return sh_entropy

#importing the MSA file
#importing the clustal file
align_clustal1 =AlignIO.read("/home/clustal.aln", "clustal")

def shannon_entropy_list_msa(alignment_file):
    shannon_entropy_list = []
    for col_no in range(len(list(alignment_file[0]))):
        list_input = list(alignment_file[:, col_no])
        shannon_entropy_list.append(shannon_entropy(list_input))
    return shannon_entropy_list

clustal_omega1 = shannon_entropy_list_msa(align_clustal1)

# Plotting the data
plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
plt.plot(clustal_omega1, 'r')
plt.xlabel('Residue', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Shannon's entropy", fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Edit 1:
Here is what my graph looks like after implementing the "pchip" method. link for the pchip output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3KW.png

Answer (score 1):

[pchip monotonic spline output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqvJf.png)

One approach would be to use PCHIP interpolation, which will give you the monotonic curve with the required behaviour for zero values on the y-axis.

We can't run your exact code example on our machines because you point to a local Clustal file in your 'home' directory.

Here's a simple working example, with link to output image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import pchip


mylist = [10,0,0,0,0,9,9,0,0,0,11,11,11,0,0]
mylist_np = np.array(mylist)
samples = np.array(range(len(mylist)))    
xnew = np.linspace(samples.min(), samples.max(), 100)
plt.plot(xnew,pchip(samples, mylist_np )(xnew))
plt.show()
```

[image: plot from code]

Comment: Thank you so much. I just had another doubt. Let's say that "mylist" contains a large number of data points, for example, in my case it will be around 1200 points. So when I implement the pchip method, the curve that I get is almost similar to that of the plot that I was getting. Not a good representation that I would like. I have edited my question. If you can have a look at what I am talking about. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, we can't run your data because it depends on your local file: but if you post *just the data* output, we can address the cubic-monotonic plotting for you ...